# Radare2 cannot debug on windows 7

Tags: windows, debugging, gdb, radare2

I downloaded radare 2.5 for windows. I am trying to debug a binary on windows with radare and have tried the following:

```
radare2 -d a.exe
fork_and_ptraceme/CreateProcess: The request is not supported.
w32_dbg_maps/w32_OpenProcess: The parameter is incorrect.
[w] Cannot open 'dbg://a.exe' for writing.
```

I also tried to use gdbserver and use radare to connect remotely. It connects but it gets stuck and I am not able to give it any commands or see anything.

I am going to try windbg remote as well, however, I am starting to wonder, do I need to install another set of libraries or another type of debugger, or do some additional configuration to make debugging work with radare2. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you use a 32-bit or a 64-bit machine? Is the executable you are trying to debug is 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: @Megabeets I was using 32 bit version, it turns out. Switched to 64bit and things are looking peachy.

Comment: Yup. That's what I thought. It's a bitness problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most probably using radare2 version downloaded by following the link on the official website (http://radare.mikelloc.com/get/2.5.0/radare2_installer-msvc_32-2.5.0.exe). The link is to the 32-bit application, but you need to open [the directory](http://radare.mikelloc.com/get/2.5.0/) and download the 64-bit radare2 version.
Just encountered this issue myself.